# Java: Stream desktop to Android

Tags: java, android, remote-desktop, live-streaming

I need to create a Window application which streams desktop to Android(live).

I would need a starting point to do this job.

First I have red about VLCJ but I have 2 problems with it.

- 1'st: I took a probe with VLC player to stream my desktop to Android with the following way:

  ```
  :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,fps=5,scale=1,width=400,height=240,acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/test} :sout-all :ttl=12 :sout-keep
  ```

  I had a big delay! Like 15 sec.
- 2'nd problem is that I have to take effect to stream during it. eg: I have to zoom. I don't know that is is possible with VLCJ or not but I didn't found any way to do this.

So now I would need an another way to do my job.

Would somebody help me to do this thing with some recommendations or an example code if it possible ?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) protocol.